# Does Django have exception for an immediate http response?

Tags: python, django

Django-Tastypie has `ImmediateHttpResponse` exception which allow to return to the client an immediate response:

```
raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response='a message')
```

Django has [Http404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception), but i couldn't find a more universal exception like `ImmediateHttpResponse`.

What technique do you use to return to client an immediate 400 response?

For example having model:

```
class Subscriber(Model):

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse('Deleting subcribers is not allowed!')
```

and trying to delete an object would return to the client a `400` response with the given message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) which implements a [process_exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process_exception).

It works like this: you raise an Exception on you view (e.g. ImmediateHttpResponse). If the exception is catched by your middleware, the middleware returns a response, in your case the with a status 400. If you don't catch the exception, Django will catch it in the end, returning a status 500 (server error), or other status.

The simplest example is a middleware that catches Http404. If you catch the exception Http404 in your middleware, you can return any response you want (status 200, 400, etc). If you don't catch (i.e. the process_exception method of you middleware returns None), Django will catch it for you and return a Response with status 404. This is actually the standard way of having your own custom exceptions that you want to respond in a custom way.

Comment: Yes, i am aware if [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651031/does-django-have-exception-for-an-immediate-http-response#comment25705215_17651081).

Answer (score 2):

It is not an exception, but there is [`HttpResponseBadRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseBadRequest), which is your normal `HttpResponse` but with `400`.

The `Http404` exception is simply [an empty `Exception` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L455), there is nothing special about it:

```
class Http404(Exception):
    pass
```

So you can easily create your own if you must:

```
class Http400(Exception):
    pass
```

[`ImmediateHttpResponse`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/exceptions.py#L82) isn't that much different than `Http404` in that its also a generic `Exception` but with a specific property, which makes it more like `HttpResponseBadRequest`:

```
class ImmediateHttpResponse(TastypieError):
    """
    This exception is used to interrupt the flow of processing to immediately
    return a custom HttpResponse.

    Common uses include::

        * for authentication (like digest/OAuth)
        * for throttling

    """
    _response = HttpResponse("Nothing provided.")

    def __init__(self, response):
        self._response = response

    @property
    def response(self):
        return self._response
```

Comment: This is a `HttpResponse` class, i need an exception, which i can raise in any place, not only in views

Comment: Django treats `django.http.Http404` exception in a special way, rendering `404` template. I want another special exception which will return to client a `400` response with the given message. I can define a custom exception and write a middleware that will catch it rendering a `400` response, but i was wondering if there is already such a thing in Django.

Comment: That's exactly what `HttpResponseBadRequest` is for; since its a normal `HttpResponse`, you can send back any additional payload with it.

Comment: I could use `HttpResponseBadRequest`, but then i need to put logic into the view. I don't want to touch the view, i want to raise exception at any level.

Comment: Putting an `ImmediateHttpResponse` exception in your models is the same as putting logic into the view. Your model should not be aware of the implementation layer (HTTP? TCP? why does it matter?), so you should just create your own exception (e.g., `NotAllowedOperation`), then your view will catch this exception and will return an `HttpResponseBadRequest`.

Comment: I think @Markon is incorrect. I want a function that parses the incoming request's json, if the parsing fails I want to return the 400 status code. This should go into a json parsing function (calls json.load and raises an exception if something went bad), and not in the view itself.

Comment: @zmbq If the parsing of json fails, then you must raise a different exception, e.g., "InputValidationException", then the above layer must communicate with the client on the same layer, e.g., HTTP, and therefore you can specify a 400 status code.