# Django: How to catch a specific exception in a class based view during template rendering?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How do you catch a specific exception during Django template rendering in a class based view?

I have a custom exception `ImmediateHttpResponse` which is intended to cause an immediate redirect in my class based view.  I have tried:

```
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return super(AppConnectionsView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
    except ImmediateHttpResponse as e:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(e.response)
```

The exception I am trying to catch is raised in a template tag and so it seems the exception is intercepted by django's template debug and I get a template render error `HttpResponseRedirect no exception supplied`.  I still want to debug my templates, just not when HttpResponseRedirect is raised.

Please hold all comments about not raising errors in template tags...  I have an extremely good reason.

Comment: Maybe the response is in middleware. See that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651031/does-django-have-exception-for-an-immediate-http-response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really have to do it at any cost, here is a simple solution:

```
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(AppConnectionsView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        response.render()
    except ImmediateHttpResponse as e:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(e.response)
    return response
```

The reason why you cannot catch render errors in the view is because although response is created in the view, it is actually rendered by [`BaseHandler`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/core/handlers/base.py#L23), which handles all errors appropriately. Downside of above solution is that it will render the template twice per request.

The only other way to be able to catch your custom error is to customize the `BaseHandler` (or it's derivative, like a `WSGIHandler`), which obviously would eliminate that double rendering issue.

Say you are using `wsgi`, as you probably should :) you can do something like that:

```
import django
from django.utils import six
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler as DjangoWSGIHandler
from my_app.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse

class WSGIHandler(DjangoWSGIHandler):
    def handle_uncaught_exception(self, request, resolver, exc_info):
        (type, value, traceback) = exc_info
        if type is not None and issubclass(type, ImmediateHttpResponse):
            six.reraise(*exc_info)
        return super(WSGIHandler, self).handle_uncaught_exception(
            request, resolver, exc_info)

def get_wsgi_application():
    django.setup()
    return WSGIHandler()
```

Now you can use this function in `wsgi.py`:

```
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Interesting. Meddling with that handler might not be wise I must say

Comment: @Alvaro that is why I introduced a simple solution to the problem first. :) At the same time, it doesn't change any behavior of the handler, but a mere exception type checking, so I don't think it should be a big deal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Makes sense. It's been a while and i don't remember how i got around this (prob stopped raising errors in template tags ;).